# Pointer as function argument

Tags: c++, arrays, function, arguments

I wrote a similar code some time ago, and it worked but for some reason this doesn't and I can't figure out what i left out or did wrong.

```
int fn(int *pArg)
{
    if(*pArg!=NULL)
        return *pArg+fn(pArg+1);
    else
        return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int nArray[128],i,nLenght;
    std::cin>>nLenght;
    for(i=1;i<=nLenght;i++)
        std::cin>>nArray[i];
    std::cout<<"The sum of the array is: "<<fn(nArray);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "This doesn't work" is not a question about a programming language. Try harder.

Comment: -1. This program doesn't even compile because `n` is not declared. Please post code that at least passes the compiler.

Comment: @larsmans: Your answer was correct, though..

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: undeleted it, although I'm not sure I interpreted the OP's intention correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This program is flawed in many ways, one of which being that

```
*pArg!=NULL
```

compares an `int` with the null pointer constant. Do `pArg != NULL` instead.

(And note that `fn` is flawed; it will try to recurse until the pointer wraps around to `NULL`, but will probably due to stack overflow long before that happens.)

Comment: I tried with `pArg != NULL`. Still doesn't work and this time doesn't return anything.

Comment: @UrecheVlad: That's because you chose to completely ignore the final paragraph.

Comment: Ok... do you have a fix or something?

Comment: @UrecheVlad: This isn't http://gimme-teh-codez.com. You have to do your own work. We merely answer questions and guide you. Revisit the design of your algorithm, on paper.

Comment: Than a little hint perhaps... I really can't see where I was wrong.

Comment: @UrecheVlad: here's a hint; incrementing a pointer to point beyond an array doesn't make the pointer null. You have to pass the number of elements to the summing function.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::cin>>a[i];
```

This line should be:

```
std::cin>>nArray[i];
```